# Почему нет беззнакового double?

Tags: c#, типы-данных, .net

Почему нет беззнакового double?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.decimal.aspx

Comment: Вероятно, по тому, что "без знаковый `double`", это уже не `double`, короче, используйте int64

Comment: В [`IEE754`][1] нет понятия `unsigned` вещественного числа, поэтому его нет и в `C#`.

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: А, собственно, почему нет такового понятия. Ну это оттого, что платформа .NET **is really so smart!**, она берет на себя множество обязанностей "на аппаратном уровне", освобождая от них программиста. Это всем известно и так =) Так вот, понятие signed/unsigned это тоже, по сути лежит в аппаратном уровне. Платформа сами решает, какой регистр можно будет в дальнейшем использовать для хранения числа. Если число со знаком, то, возможно, даже связку регисров(да, бывали такие случаи!) типа EAX:ECX, ну, а если без знака, то ничего сложного - любой "свободный" 32 битный регистр =)

Comment: Потому что в реальных задачах беззнаковый double никому не нужен.

Comment: @Asen, ну почему нет возможности *легко* минусовать комментарии? 

Вопрос про double, а Вы про 32-bit регистры. Я уже не говорю о том, что далеко не все, что есть в языке (платформе) должно напрямую поддерживаться аппаратурой.

Comment: @Asen

- **Причем здесь регистры вообще?**

- `IEE754` специфицирует набор некоторых вещественных типов (`binary16 - 128` и аналогичные им `decimal`), в которых в соответствующем количестве бит записывается информация. Через какие регистры передавать данную информацию - это личное дело текущей платформы с точностью до `ABI`.

- В `IEE754` **нет** понятия беззнакового вещественного числа. Вы можете написать и утвердить свой стандарт, в котором это понятие будет и будет описан способ его кодирования, но это уже не будет `IEE754,` который реализован в платформах типа `.NET`

Comment: Само по себе "signed/unsigned" относится к регистрам, вот я и решил сделать "небольшое отступление" для разъяснений автору, что в C# нет необходимости париться со всеми аппаратными тонкостями.

Comment: За такие вопросы надо расстреливать без сожаления! Это примерно то же самое что и спрашивать почему натуральный ряд не включает отрицательные числа!

Comment: @Asen По `IEE754` в закодированном представлении числа есть один бит `s (sign),` который отвечает за его знак. Так что `signed / unsigned` в этом случае относится к процессорным регистрам точно так же, как и этот комментарий.

Comment: @Asen, а в каком языке высокого уровня есть "необходимость париться со всеми аппаратными тонкостями"?

Comment: @avp Возможно в php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что тип double хранит число с плавающей запятой. Его значащие цифры и порядок хранятся отдельно. В отличие от обычных чисел, где порядок выражается количеством нулей, являющихся значащими цифрами.

Из-за такого сложного способа хранения числа к нему нельзя применять быстрые операции сдвига, потому что они всё поломают. Ведь они манипулируют двоичными разрядами, а порядок выражает степень десятки. Это исключает половину трюков, для реализации которых беззнаковый тип был бы полезен. Другую половину исключает то, что с плавающими числами нельзя производить операции по модулю. В результате беззнаковый тип почти полностью обессмысливается.

Из преимуществ остаётся только экономия одного бита на знаке. Очевидно, этого оказалось недостаточно, чтобы разработчики процессоров сделали знаковый бит частью числа. Они предпочли сильно упростить себе жизнь и хранить его отдельно. Разработчики же языков на своём уровне, естественно, не могут эффективно задействовать этот лишний бит для хранения значащего разряда.

Comment: Это я немного затупил. В машинном представлении порядок, конечно, выражает степень шестнадцати. Хотя десятка тоже возможна, но на уровне языка или даже библиотеки, реализующей BCD-арифметику.

Comment: Вообще в http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008 упоминается несколько архитектур с десятичной арифметикой с плавающей точкой. Только вот я с ними никогда не сталкивался (и ранее даже не слышал)

Comment: Я про такие тоже не знаю. Десятичную экспоненту видел только в реализации BCD-чисел.

Answer (score 3):

Стандарт [IEEE 754-2008](https://www.iso.org/standard/57469.html), описывающий формат чисел с плавающей запятой, предписывает хранить отдельно знак, модуль и масштабный коэффициент:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У целых чисел знак хранят и выводят неявно, основываясь на особенностях переполнения. У дробных же чисел знак записывается явно, что позволяет, кстати, хранить ещё и отрицательный ноль, востребованный в мат. анализе.

К сожалению для вас, избавиться от знакового бита не удастся — вы нарушите стандарт и часть процессора, отвечающая за дробные числа, вас просто не поймёт. Из-за этого вам придётся реализовывать всю работу с дробными числами с нуля.